# What fd's are used when doing diff <(cat old) <(cat new)?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors, process-substitution

If I do:

```
diff <(cat old) <(cat new)
```

Hoe does that work internally for the diff program? And how I do the same trick with a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it yourself:

```
echo <(echo) <(echo)
```

Diff just reads from both the files.

If you want to use `<(...)` as a parameter to your bash script, just keep in mind you can't "rewind" the file (or reopen). So once you read it, it's gone. You can use `read` to process it line by line, you can `grep` it or whatever. If you need to process it more than once, either save its content to a variable

```
input=$(cat "$1"; printf x) # The "x" keeps the trailing empty lines.
input=${input%x}
```

or copy it to a temporary file and read it over and over:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat "$1" > "$tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `diff` program there is no difference as if you type `diff old new`. The `<(cmd)` operator redirects the stdout of `cmd1` to a fifo and then pass the fifo as an argument to `diff`.

See an example:

```
user@host:~$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

`/dev/fd/63` is the fifo containing the output of `ls`, see `cat <(ls)` prints the output of the fifo, hence the ouput of `ls`.

So, the `diff` program is executed as something like this:

```
diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/64
```

And both fifos contain the output of the cmds. For `diff` they are files.